# Django - Multiples slugs/pk en URL dependiendo de aplicación previa

Tags: django, django-models, url, django-urls, slug

Tengo dos aplicaciones dentro de Django, una de cursos, y otra para las asignaciones. Todo anda bien lo que pasa es que por ejemplo para entrar al curso está la siguiente URL:

https://localhost/curso/7

y para entrar a la asignación de ese curso es:

https://localhost/asignacion/1

Lo que me gustaría es que para ingresar a la asignación se concatene con la url anterior quedando:

https://localhost/curso/7/asignacion/1

Lo que tengo en las urls.py es lo siguiente:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.detallesCurso.as_view(), name='detalles-curso'),

re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.detallesAsignacion.as_view(), name='detalles-asignacion'),
```

Pero no se si deba cambiar alguna cosa en el views de cada uno o en la vista solamente de la asignación, y de alguna manera llamar al curso en esa vista y que quede algo así:

```
re_path(r'curso/^(?P<pk_1>[-\w]+)/asignacion/^(?P<pk_2>[-\w]+)/$', views.detallesAsignacion.as_view(), name='detalles-asignacion'),
```

Comment: Hola, si puedes comparte un ejemplo del template donde usas el enlace "detalles-asignacion" que es el que quieres que tenga la forma https://localhost/curso/7/asignacion/1

Comment: Deberías si usas el curso en la vista de la asignación. Pero por el ejemplo anterior no lo necesitas.